# SIGTTIN problem

Tags: c

I have written a sample program to simulate the SIGTTIN. It looks as follows:

```
// Some include files

void sigfn(int num)
{
   printf("\n SIGTTIN CAUGHT \n");
}  

int main()
{
    signal(SIGTTIN , sigfn);
    read(0, .., ..);
    write(1, .., ..);

    return 0;
}
```

But when I run this in the foreground, I get an output which print the following in an infinite loop:

```
SIGTTIN CAUGHT
SIGTTIN CAUGHT
SIGTTIN CAUGHT
SIGTTIN CAUGHT
SIGTTIN CAUGHT
SIGTTIN CAUGHT
SIGTTIN CAUGHT
.
.
.
.
```

I understand this is because read is a blocking system call, but how do I stop it?
I am closing the terminal right now. Please help me out as to how to stop it and why this works.

Comment: How do you stop what exactly?

Comment: Im not getting an infinite loop when running in foreground. I get it when running in backgroud (such as in `$./sim_ttin&`), and its fine, because its what its supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

void sigfn(int num){
   printf("sigttin");                                                           
}

int main(){
   char c;

   signal(SIGTTIN,sigfn);

   read(0,&c,1);
   
   printf("%c\n",c);
   return 0;

}
```

I'm not getting an infinite loop when running in foreground. It does [what it should](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGTTIN) and block until there's something to read.

```
$ ./sim_ttin
```

To stop it (I'm guessing you mean [kill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_%28command%29) it), just open another console, look for the process and kill it.

This is what I did. In one console:

> $./sim_ttin &
> nsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttin

Then I opened another console and typed:

```
$ps aux | grep sim_ttin
user     4350  6.0  0.0   1620   340 pts/0    S    22:58   0:00 ./sim_ttin
```

4350 is the pid. Just kill it

```
$ kill -9 4350
```

Let's check the first console:

> insigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttinsigttins
>
> [1]+  Killed                  ./sim_ttin

Comment: How do u stop it in the same window .. ?